# Что такое "ежовые рукавицы"?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

"Держать в ежовых рукавицах" — значит, в строгости, даже чрезмерной.
А что такое эти *ежовые рукавицы*?
Действительно ли делали рукавицы из шкурок ежей и зачем?

Answer (score 6):

Ежовые рукавица делались не из шкурок ежей, а для ловли ежей.  Ежовые рукавицы (голицы) - рабочие кожаные рукавицы без подкладки и меха, они предназначались  для ловли ежей (их приносили для того, чтобы они мышей ловили,).

Answer (score 2):

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА

"Вспомним род князей Голицыных. Своей фамилией они обязаны широко известным в узких кругах голицам. Так назывались рабочие верхонки из грубой кожи без шерстяных или меховых подкладок. Облачившись в них, можно безболезненно для себя делать почти всё что угодно: хоть ежей ловить. Этому нехитрому занятию с их помощью преимущественно и предавались. Ну, а голицы оттого прозвище получили – «ежовые рукавицы».

Фразеологический оборот «взять кого-то в ежовые рукавицы» родился из русской поговорки «ежовыми рукавицами да за мягкое тело приниматься». Также известна пословица: «Ежовая голица – учить мастерица».

Answer (score 0):

Получается, что правы обе — и София, и Ларf:
Ларf верно объяснила, почему "ежовые": для ловли мышей использовали ежей. Но как заманить его в нужное помещение? А как раз для этого и нужны ежовые рукавицы – голицы. Они делались из толстой кожи без подкладки. Такими-то и можно взять колючего ежа, свернувшегося в клубок, и отнести  к новым охотничьим угодьям. А потом, когда он с мышиной напастью справится, выпустить на волю.
http://newslab.ru/blog/165891

София верно раскрыла смысл использования выражения в значении "держать в строгости". В XVIII веке в словарях зафиксирована пословица: «Ежовыми рукавицами да за мягкое тело приниматься». Чуть позже — «Ежовая голица – учить мастерица». Смысл: ограничить свободу, отнестись грубо, но для пользы дела. К ежам ведь тоже грубо относились, но польза всем была — и им, и людям. Так и в воспитании нужны строгость и ограничение свободы. *Есть же у нас пословица: Если хочешь, чтобы ребёнок умер, дай ему полную свободу.*

А вот зловещий смысл приобрела поговорка во времена Ежова, когда в НКВД применяли пытки и зажимали руки в пыточные инструменты, их тоже называли "ежовыми рукавицами".

Comment: Мне кажется, что развитие значения  шло по такому пути:воспитывать - это держать в руках, не давать полной свободы; а если на руки одеть грубые рукавицы, то получится строгое воспитание. Здесь самым важным моментом является тот факт, что рукавицы жесткие, а не то, что они предназначены для ежей.

Comment: жёсткие - объяснение к слову"ежовые", а важно, что ограничили свободу.

Comment: Сомневаюсь,  что  голицы  шились  для  ловли  ежей - кузнецам  они  гораздо  нужней.  Да и не нужно  особых  приспособ,  чтобы  поймать  ежа,  иглы  у  него  не  стальные  и  не  ядовитые.  Можно даже  голыми  руками  взять  или  какой-нибудь  тряпкой  захватить.  Фразеологизму  "держать  в  ежовых  рукавицах"  необязательно  опираться  на  существование  такого  элемента  рабочей  одежды  в  действительности.
Можно  основываться  именно  на  абсурдности  такой  рукавицы  в  быту.

Comment: Но,  с  другой  стороны,  может  и  было  что-то,  что  могло  называться  ежовыми рукавицами  потому,  что  надевалось  на  руку  и  было  сшито  из  ежовой  шкурки.   "Сами по себе ежи небесполезны для жизни человека, как думают многие из нас, поскольку, если бы у них не было иголок, мягкие шкуры домашнего скота были бы бесполезны для смертных: ведь ежовая шкурка используется для выделки одежды. " (Плиний Старший, Естественная история VIII. 135).   Пример,  правда,  из  древнеримской   истории,  но  может  на  Руси  ими  так  же  пользовались.

Comment: > Держать кого ежевыми рукавицами [в ежовых рукавицах, нарукавниках]. Обращаться с кем-л. строго, не давая воли. Отец тогда сего дѣтины Взбѣсясь женился на другой, Которая его сѣдины Сѣдѣе дѣлала собой; **Держала на вожжах моржовых, И в нарукавниках ежовых**. Оспв Енеида IV 107.  
ФЭБ, СлРЯ 18 в.